# Store 4 different values in a byte

Tags: c, hex, byte

I have an assignment to do, but I have no clue where to start. I am not expecting and definitely do not want answers in code. I would like some guidance as in what to do because I feel a bit lost.

Pack and unpack variables into a byte . You need to store 4 different values in a byte. The values are:

```
NAME       RANGE  BITS   
engine_on  0-1    1

gear_pos   0-4    3 

key_pos    0-2    2 

brake1     0-1    1

brake2     0-1    1
```

(LSB, Least significant bit )

Write a program bytess.c that takes 5 arguments (less or more should be treated as an error). The arguments should correspond to the values/variables above.
Example:
bytess 1 2 2 1 1

The above should be treated as:
Name Value
engine_on 1 
gear_pos 2 
key_pos 2
brake1 1
brake2 1

Pack these values together in a byte (unsigned char) as an integer and print it out to stdout in hexadecimal form , in this example it should be ‘AB’ corresponding to bits ‘10101011. After this your program should return 0. If your program finds anything wrong (too many/few arguments, faulty input values.. ) your program should print error and return a not zero value.

I know how to check if those are 5 args, but I do not understand what to do next. Ive already read so much information about shifting but my brain can not handle the whole picture. It feels like this should be a really easy example, but I can not find anything on internet that would be similar. 
How does "AB" become 10101011? Ive just checked String to hex -> 4142. hex to bit -> 1000000101110.

Comment: You might want to read about [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), and maybe unions. And if those are not okay to use, then about the bitwise operators AND `&`, OR `&` and NOT `~`.

Comment: I have read about them but I do not see where I may use them here.

Comment: Shift operators (`<<` and/or `>>`) would be helpful: you can take one of your field's values, and shift it so that it occupies the desired range of bits.  The use bitwise or (`|`) to combine the individual field values into the composite you want.

Comment: look into the format `"%02x"` to print in hex.

Comment: `AB` is a hex number, normally written by C programmers as `0xAB`. The hex number `A` has bit pattern `1010`, and `B` is `1011`, so together they are `10101011`. If you separate the different items in that bit pattern, you have `1 010 10 1 1` in binary, which is `1 2 2 1 1` in decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets call a byte b, if you set b to 0, you end up with (binary) 0000 0000 (space for readability)

Now we want to pack the different parts into this byte

```
engine_on  0-1    1
gear_pos   0-4    3 
key_pos    0-2    2 
brake1     0-1    1
brake2     0-1    1
```

brake2 is simple. We can just set b to the value of brake2 and we will end up with 0000 0000, or 0000 0001 depending on if it is a 0 or a 1.

now we want to set brake 1 to b. We can do this by using a or/equal and the number itself but bitshifted to the right position. We end up with the following:

```
b |= (brake1 << 1)
```

lets explain how I came at this:

```
brake1 = 0000 0001 //lets assume its a 1 not a 0)
(brake1 << 1) = 0000 0010
b = 0000 0001 //lets assume brake 2 was 1.
```

to 'add' the value from brake1 to b we have to set each bit if either the bit in b is 1 or if the bit in (brake1 << 1) is one. This is done by a 'bitwise-or', so we end up with:

```
b = b | (brake1 << 1) // which can also be written as:
b |= (brake1 << 1)
```

now you can also add the other parts, it also works with more bits at the same time. I hope this has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

Have you read about bit field?

```
struct s {
  unsigned char engine_on : 1;
  unsigned char gear_pos : 3;
  unsigned char key_pos : 2;
  unsigned char brake1 : 1;
  unsigned char brake2 : 1;
};
```

Comment: Bitfield ordering and packing is implementation dependent.

Comment: also bitfield members should be declared  as unsigned

Comment: Ok, I read about it now. I understand that it makes my struct precisely 8 bits. How do I put these values in an integer?

Comment: you just set the structure members to the values? and then probably memcpy the structure to an integer?

Comment: or left shift the values of structure fields to match their position as per the structure and then | (bitwise or) the integer with that bitmask

Comment: @Ship It's unlikely that you're supposed to use bit fields in this assignment. All you really need is the left shift operator `<<` and the 'or' operator `|`.

Comment: @user3386109 Why do I need the OR operator here?

Comment: bad implementation, not portable and lot endian problems. stay away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it.

```
    unsigned int i = 0;

    engine_on = 1;
    gear_pos =2;
    key_pos = 2;
    brake1 = 1;
    brake2 = 1;

    i |= s1.brake2;
    i |= (s1.brake1 << 1);
    i |= (s1.key_pos << 2);
    i |= (s1.gear_pos << 4);
    i |= (s1.engine_on << 7);
```