# How to pack numbers into specific bits of a byte?

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation, bit, endianness

Lets say there is a `byte` array. I want to pack the number `0x3` in `bit3..bit2` of the `byte 0` and number `0x3` in `bit1..bit0` of the `byte 0`. Other bits of the byte can contaion `0`s. The byte order is `little endian`.

I am fairly new to byte manipulation and I am not sure how I can achieve this in `C` programming. I am sorry if the explanation of the problem is not good.

Comment: Endianness does not apply to packing a **byte**

Comment: Anything wrong with direct assignment? `char c=0xf`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala So, it matters only when packing a `byte` with an `8-bit` value?

Comment: @Dennis.M (byte) endianness is all about packing of bytes of a multibyte value in a multibyte buffer. The bit endianness is a thing but it seldom occurs with programming. The bits are always numbered according to the powers of 2 that their integer values are.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am having a byte array. I edited my question.

Comment: It still does not matter. Please read the linked duplicate and you can then ask more precise question if it does not answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am not understanding your linked SO discussion. Could you give me a bit more explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507646/store-4-different-values-in-a-byte this q/a? did you read it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Got it! My understanding with endianness was wrong.

Comment: use multiplications by 2 (or <<) and additions of 1.